# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roll')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I keep running into this error. I have tried defining the variables but it still does not seem to work. I may be doing this wrong or its something very small but i cant seem to figure it out. I would appreciate the help.

Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

this is another error which im guessing is from the same issue.

This is my code below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Col, Row } from "reactstrap";
import Loading from "./LoadingComponent";

class Issue extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isbn: "",
      roll: "",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.booksLoading || this.props.usersLoading) {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <Loading />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else if (this.props.booksErrMess) {
      return (
        <div className="container loading">
          <div className="row heading">
            <div className="col-12">
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <h3>{this.props.booksErrMess}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else if (this.props.usersErrMess) {
      return (
        <div className="container loading">
          <div className="row heading">
            <div className="col-12">
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <h3>{this.props.usersErrMess}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

```
else {
      const bookoptions = this.props.books.map((book, index) => (
        <option key={book.isbn}>{book.isbn}</option>
      ));

      const defaultBook = this.props.books[0];
      // To just get list of the students (not the admins)
      let useroptions = this.props.users.filter((user) => !user.admin);
      const defaultUser = useroptions[0];
      useroptions = useroptions.map((user, index) => (
        <option key={user.roll}>{user.roll}</option>
      ));


      if (this.state.isbn === "") {
        this.setState({ isbn: defaultBook.isbn, roll: defaultUser.roll });
      }

      return (
        <div className="container full">
          <div className="row justify-content-center heading">
            <div className="col-12">
              <h3 align="center"> Issue book</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row row-content justify-content-center">
            <Form
              onSubmit={(e) => {
                let bookid = this.props.books.filter(
                  (book) => book.isbn === this.state.isbn
                )[0]._id;
                let studentid = this.props.users.filter(
                  (user) => user.roll === this.state.roll
                )[0]._id;
                this.props.postIssue(bookid, studentid);
                e.preventDefault();
              }}
            >
              <FormGroup row>
                <Label htmlFor="isbn"> ISBN No.of book</Label>
                <Input
                  type="select"
                  defaultValue={defaultBook.name}
                  name="isbn"
                  id="isbn"
                  className="form-control"
                  onInput={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ isbn: e.target.value });
                  }}
                >
                  {bookoptions}
                </Input>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup row>
                <Label htmlFor="roll"> Roll No. of student </Label>
                <Input
                  type="select"
                  id="roll"
                  className="form-control"
                  onInput={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ roll: e.target.value });
                  }}
                >
                  {useroptions}
                </Input>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup row>
                <Label htmlFor="name"> Name of book </Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  id="name"
                  name="name"
                  placeholder="Name of Book"
                  defaultValue={defaultBook.name}
                  value={
                    !this.state.isbn
                      ? ""
                      : this.props.books.filter(
                          (book) => book.isbn === this.state.isbn
                        )[0].name
                  }
                  className="form-control"
                  disabled
                />
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup row>
                <Label htmlFor="author"> Authors </Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  id="author"
                  name="author"
                  placeholder="Name of authors"
                  defaultValue={defaultBook.author}
                  value={
                    !this.state.isbn
                      ? ""
                      : this.props.books.filter(
                          (book) => book.isbn === this.state.isbn
                        )[0].author
                  }
                  className="form-control"
                  disabled
                />
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup row>
                <Label htmlFor="name_student"> Name of student </Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  id="name_student"
                  name="name_student"
                  placeholder="Name of student"
                  defaultValue={
                    defaultUser.firstname + " " + defaultUser.lastname
                  }
                  value={
                    !this.state.roll
                      ? ""
                      : this.props.users.filter(
                          (user) => user.roll === this.state.roll
                        )[0].firstname +
                        " " +
                        this.props.users.filter(
                          (user) => user.roll === this.state.roll
                        )[0].lastname
                  }
                  className="form-control"
                  disabled
                />
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup row>
                <Label htmlFor="username"> Username of student </Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  id="username"
                  name="username"
                  placeholder="Username of student"
                  defaultValue={defaultUser.username}
                  value={
                    !this.state.roll
                      ? ""
                      : this.props.users.filter(
                          (user) => user.roll === this.state.roll
                        )[0].username
                  }
                  className="form-control"
                  disabled
                />
              </FormGroup>
              <Row className="align-self-center">
                <Col className="text-center">
                  <Button type="submit" className="bg-primary">
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Form>
          </div>
          <br />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Issue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is reading from undefined, the only possible source of error should be `user.roll` or `defaultUser.roll`.

```
let useroptions = this.props.users.filter((user) => !user.admin);
const defaultUser = useroptions[0];
useroptions = useroptions.map((user, index) => (
  <option key={user.roll}>{user.roll}</option>
));
```

Add an undefined check before using defaultUser and useroptions.

```
if (defaultUser) {
  ...
}
```